# JFrame frame calls JPanel paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am actually learning Graphics in Java. I cannot understand how this `JFrame` object calls the `paintComponent` method in `MyDrawpanel` which extends `JPanel`.

The `frame.repaint()` call again the `paintComponent` but how? Why I cannot use `drawPanel` object of `MyDrawPanel` like `drawPanel.repaint()`;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change Colors");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        int red = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random() * 255);

        Color randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `repaint()` tells the paint manager to paint the component and all sub-components that it holds. It's part of the painting "chain".

Comment: Check out:  [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics.  AND  [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Comment: but how frame object calls that repaint()

Comment: Short answer is "it's complicated" and sometimes, you need to accept a little bit of "black magic" until you obtain enough experience with the API.  Having said that, you should have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how the paint system works

Comment: *"but how frame object calls that repaint()*" - And paint request is by the frame in response to `setSize` and `setVisible`. Not all methods do this, but some have to in order to trigger a layout/paint pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I cannot use drawPanel object of MyDrawPanel like drawPanel.repaint();

Currently your `frame` variable is defined as an `instance` variable so it can be referenced in any method of the class.

However your `drawPanel` variable is defined as a `local` variable so it can only be referenced in the method where it is defined.

Change the `drawPanel` variable so it is defined as `instance` variable, not a `local` variable. Then you can use `drawPanel.repaint()` in the `actionPerformed(...)` method.

Invoking repaint() on the panel would be more efficient since only the panel will be repainted, not the frame and the button.

Also, you are using an old version of the add(...) method.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
```

You should be using:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

and the frame will now forward add(...) requests to the content pane so you can actually just use:

```
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to save yourself some typing.